# Can every regular language have a linear bounded automaton

Tags: automata

As the question states:

I am trying to understand automata. Can every regular language have a linear bounded automaton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: linear bounded automata are acceptors for context-sensitive languages, and regular languages are context-sensitive.